# If/else Javascript statement not working properly with DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have the following Javascript code that initializes a DataTables chart on my website.

Basically, my intention with this script is to AJAX in different data based upon the URL the user is currently on. I have written an if/else statement that worked for other components on my page but is not working for my [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) chart.

Why is this not working? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
var URL = window.location.href;

if (URL.indexOf("london") !== -1) {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects-london.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
    });
  });
}
if (URL.indexOf("nw") !== -1) {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects-nw.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
    });
  });
}
if (URL.indexOf("loupe") !== -1) {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects-loupe.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
    });
  });
}
if (URL.indexOf("new-york") !== -1) {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects-new-york.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
            } );
        }
    });
  });
}
if (URL.indexOf("content") !== -1) {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects-content.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
    });
  });
}
else {
  // initialize datatables chart
  $(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": "../financial-reports/aging-projects.php",
    "destroy": true,
    "resonsive": true,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: @KarlAnderson Google Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116.

Comment: Have you tried `if (URL.toLowerCase().indexOf("london") !== -1) {` to see if it is a case sensitivity issue?

Comment: @KarlAnderson Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that and, unfortunately, that is not what is causing the issue.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors when you run this?

Comment: @KarlAnderson No console errors are visible.

Comment: I would add `debugger;` lines until you find out where it is failing. It is a needle in a haystack problem until you can narrow down which line or lines are the issue.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Thanks for your suggestion. I will try that.

Comment: @LizBanach Simplify the code. I believe is easy if you switch to a switch. You are using several if and what about if there are no match? why not use a switch statement?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can also create a function with what is inside your `if/else` statements. Then if a statement is true, you can run that function with the according data and not have to write all that code for each case :)

Comment: Thank you for the insight @manuerumx. I am new to JavaScript and have not used a switch statement before, but after looking it up it seems like it might work well.

Comment: @DanielD Thank you for the insight. That is a much better way of doing things. I am new to JavaScript so that helps a lot.

Comment: The error in the original code I think is that everything is inside an separate if blocks and the last thing is inside an if...else block.
So when for example the url contains london, the code goes into the first if block and then inside the last else block as well.
Everything should be inside if...else blocks

I would prefer the solution that manuerumx gave from a code organisation perspective.

Comment: Thank you @klikas. That makes good sense. I appreciate all of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see an error, but maybe if you change the code in this way, should be more easy to debug and find the error.

```
var URL = window.location.href;
var ajaxURL = '';

if (URL.indexOf("london") !== -1) {
  ajaxURL = 'aging-projects-london.php';
}else if (URL.indexOf("nw") !== -1) {
  ajaxURL = 'aging-projects-nw.php';
}else if (URL.indexOf("loupe") !== -1) {
  ajaxURL = 'aging-projects-loupe.php';
}else if (URL.indexOf("new-york") !== -1) {
    ajaxURL = 'aging-projects-new-york.php'; 
}else if (URL.indexOf("content") !== -1) {
    ajaxURL = 'aging-projects-content.php'; 
}else {
  ajaxURL = 'aging-projects.php'; 
}
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#aging_projects').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": "../financial-reports/" + ajaxURL,
        "destroy": true,
        "resonsive": true,
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                        );

                    column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
                } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @manuerumx. This is much cleaner than the mess I originally had and helped me track down the issue.

Comment: Glad i can help you @LizBanach